# The spectrum of a not necessarily quasi-coherent sheaf of Algebras and a related vague question.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory, schemes, ringed-spaces

See [this answer on Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/148976/124352) and [this wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_of_a_ring#Global_or_relative_Spec).

These links claim that one can construct $Spec \mathcal{A}$ for any sheaf of algebras over a scheme(and even for any locally ringed space). However, there are no references in either place. I tried to extend the construction in the quasi-coherent case, but it seems hopeless.Then I tried to imitate the construction of the Spectrum of a ring, and got something seemingly nonsensical.(My secondary question is about this.)

My Primary Question: Can anyone provide a reference for these facts?

---

This is something that occurred to me while trying to imitate the construction of the Ring spectrum. I was able to define sheaf-theoretic analogues for the usual things needed to construct an affine scheme from a ring(prime ideals, localization, etc.). But what I ended up with was a 'sheaf of sheaves'.

My Secondary(vague) question: To what extent can one extend the usual commutative algebra to (locally) ringed spaces? Does the a 'sheaf of sheaves' thing that I ended up with mean anything? If so, can anyone provide references?

Comment: As a reference I would recommend EGA2 , section 1.3.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look there.